# How to query on mongodb string date format

Tags: mongodb

In my mongodb collection i'm using String date i.e getting saved as "Sat Jan 07 10:34:14 IST 2017", i need to query based on date range, can it be possible.

Comment: No. Fix your data.

Comment: how to do with existing data any solution

Comment: Which part of **NO** is difficult for you to comprehend? It's a string. We cannot sort it, we cannot really extract data from it. We can do ridiculous operations that need to scan every item in the collection to do anything related to selecting data. But the simple fact is the data got into this state because of bad code. The code that put the data in **needs** to be fixed. As does the data.